# Updating a list of MongoDB docs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a list of documents that i want to update in mongoDB. I send it to the API as a JSON array.

How can I update all the docs without putting the Document.update() into a loop?

I was looking at the $in modifier but i'm not sure how to pass in the actual data to the method.

```
    var docs = req.body
    Card.update(
        {_id: {$in: docs}},
        {whatgoeshere?}
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **update** query with "multi":true option:

```
db.collection.update(
   <query>,
   <update>,
   {
     upsert: <boolean>,
     multi: <boolean>,
     writeConcern: <document>,
     collation: <document>
   }
)
```

Or you can use **updateMany**, added in MongoDB 3.2 version:

```
db.collection.updateMany(
   <filter>,
   <update>,
   {
     upsert: <boolean>,
     writeConcern: <document>,
     collation: <document>
   }
)
```

Comment: I have an array of documents (_id's and everything) how do i apply updateMany to that?

Comment: You don't need to pass array of documents to update query. You should only pass criteria based on which you want to update. If you are afraid that update query will replace existing document entirely, you can use **$set** operator.

Comment: I've achieved something using a for loop and creating a promise chain to do what i want as i am unable to use the $set cmd to set individual parameters.  A documents index differs from one another for example.

Comment: Your problem would become more clear if you can post your document structure. You can access embedded documents using dot notation, and you can perform update queries which are agnostic of document index. (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#update-embedded-documents-using-multiple-field-matches)